# How can I generate special characters in c#?

Tags: c#, unicode

In Notepad, when I type alt+216 it outputs a character that is not available on my keyboard keys.

I want to know how I can use this "alt+219" character in C# to generate a string containing this special character.

Is there a way to retrieve a list of these special characters?

I saw these in Office 2012 on the insert tab and in the symbols menu.
What I want to know is if it is possible to generate all of them with standard C# syntax or something?

Example:

```
╪
```

It is very interesting to me that these characters work in the editor.

Comment: Those are characters just like any other character.  Are you asking how to loop through all million+ Unicode characters?

Comment: at first i want this character that produce by this short keys(alt+216) this equal to Ø

Comment: It is one of the box drawing glyphs, '\u256a'.  Use the Charmap.exe applet on Windows instead.   Just copy/paste into your code.

Comment: You can even use many (but not all) language characters as code, allowing things like variable, method, and class names to be written in Japanese characters, for instance. But please don't.

Comment: i do not want directly type theme for some resons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can represent all Unicode characters in C#, including in string literals. There isn't so much a list of "special" characters as a [whole range of charts to look at](http://www.unicode.org/charts/). Find the character you're interested in is U+256A, as can be seen in [the box drawing chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2500.pdf) ("BOX DRAWINGS VERTICAL SINGLE AND HORIZONTAL DOUBLE").

You can use the `\u` character literal escaping format to represent the characters in C# code:

```
string text = "This is your character: \u256a";
```

The fact that the keys work in the editor is just part of Windows keyboard handling.

If you're having trouble finding a particular character, you can always save a file in Notepad using UTF-8, and then read it like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("foo.txt");
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1:x4}", c, (int) c);
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that some characters may not show up properly on the console (although the hex representation will).

Comment: Another quick way to get the hex character code for an unknown character is to open a web browser and type it into the Javascript console as `'╪'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)`.

Comment: @bobince: Nice :) Of course, I should really have provided a short but complete Windows Forms app which provides a GUI instead. I might try that later and include it in a blog post or something. It shouldn't be more than about 50 lines...

Comment: That'd be great. Oh! What I'd really like in an app like that would be to take characters as you type/paste them and show you them in hex as full code points, as UTF-16 code units and UTF-8 bytes, to make it clear how all that works. And maybe in ANSI bytes, showing which characters don't fit in the ANSI code page. And it would be awesome if it could show you *all* the encodings that contain your characters. And also it should have the moon on a stick. Hooray!

Comment: @bobince: Showing the UTF-8 encoding would be good, yes. And handling non-BMP characters to show the surrogate pair and the UTF-32 value. This is more of a challenge in terms of UI design than anything else, but I'll see what I can do...

Comment: @bobince: Implemented in C#, then did it in Javascript too. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer